# iOS - App Crash after some days - videosubcriptionsd

Tags: ios, swift

I have a very simple app that only has 3 screens and some buttons. After a couple of days working correctly it simply crashes if you press the HOME button and cannot launch it again even after a hard reset on the device.

Looking through the logs I found out that the process crashing is videosubscriptionsd. Can someone help me out figuring out what is this process? Or point me in the direction on how to fix this.

Thanks a lot

```
Incident Identifier: 322170FE-0F60-494C-A673-32BC0AFD3DF9  
    CrashReporter Key:   bfc0fc45c399e95bbf8b3b7a28a0b1d5b96447b8  
    Hardware Model:      iPad7,5  
    Process:             videosubscriptionsd [132]  
    Path:                /usr/libexec/videosubscriptionsd  
    Identifier:          videosubscriptionsd  
    Version:             ???  
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)  
    Role:                Unspecified  
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]  
    Coalition:           com.apple.videosubscriptionsd [217]  




Date/Time:           2018-06-27 10:24:33.6663 -0700  
Launch Time:         2018-06-27 10:24:33.2162 -0700  
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.3 (15E216)  
Baseband Version:    n/a  
Report Version:      104  


Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)  
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000141d4520  
VM Region Info: 0x141d4520 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4030708448  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL  
      UNUSED SPACE AT START  
--->    
      __TEXT                 00000001045d0000-00000001045d4000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ubscriptionsd  


Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11  
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb  
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]  
Triggered by Thread:  3  


Filtered syslog:  
None found  


Thread 0:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x0000000181345634 __semwait_signal_nocancel + 8  
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000018126bf38 nanosleep$NOCANCEL + 208  
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000018128f700 sleep$NOCANCEL + 44  
3   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811c02f4 _dispatch_queue_cleanup2 + 144  
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e457c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 572  
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e42cc _pthread_exit + 88  
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e4b3c pthread_exit + 44  
7   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811bda08 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 0  
8   videosubscriptionsd            0x00000001045d3b28 0x1045d0000 + 15144  
9   libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000181215fc0 start + 4  


Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit  
Thread 1:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x0000000181345a00 __sigsuspend_nocancel + 8  
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811c0388 _dispatch_sigsuspend + 28  
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811c036c _dispatch_sigsuspend + 0  


Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.126  
Thread 2:  
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x00000001813450f4 __psynch_cvwait + 8  
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e7c90 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 644  
2   Foundation                    0x000000018222dbe8 -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 780  
3   Foundation                    0x000000018227a100 -[NSOperationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished] + 256  
4   VideoSubscriberAccount        0x0000000193d7047c -[VSSubscriptionPersistentContainer _performBlock:andWait:] + 188  
5   VideoSubscriberAccount        0x0000000193d5b760 -[VSSubscriptionRegistry _performBlockAndWait:] + 156  
6   VideoSubscriberAccount        0x0000000193d5ceec -[VSSubscriptionRegistry fetchActiveSubscriptionsWithOptions:completionHandler:] + 504  
7   Foundation                    0x0000000182426960 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_EXPORTED_OBJECT_S2__ + 20  
8   Foundation                    0x00000001822256d8 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeMessageWithEvent:flags:] + 2428  
9   Foundation                    0x0000000182247ac0 message_handler + 240  
10  libxpc.dylib                  0x000000018151f220 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68  
11  libxpc.dylib                  0x000000018151cbb4 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 984  
12  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b0bb4 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16  
13  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811c74c4 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 352  
14  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811ba8f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280  
15  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811c7f70 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 508  
16  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811ba8f0 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 280  
17  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811bb380 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 336  
18  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811bbd4c _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 340  
19  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811c411c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 668  
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e3e70 _pthread_wqthread + 860  
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e3b08 start_wqthread + 4  


Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.VideoSubscriberAccount.SubscriptionMigration (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)  
Thread 3 Crashed:  
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000180a941a0 objc_retain + 16  
1   VideoSubscriberAccount        0x0000000193d704fc __59-[VSSubscriptionPersistentContainer _performBlock:andWait:]_block_invoke + 72  
2   Foundation                    0x00000001822e6e88 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16  
3   Foundation                    0x00000001822288d0 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72  
4   Foundation                    0x0000000182227cac -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 848  
5   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b0ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16  
6   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b81f4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224  
7   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b0ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16  
8   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b81f4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224  
9   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b80e0 dispatch_block_perform$VARIANT$mp + 104  
10  Foundation                    0x00000001822e8750 __NSOQSchedule_f + 376  
11  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b0ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16  
12  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b8f18 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 424  
13  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811b7850 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 604  
14  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811bdd30 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 588  
15  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001811bda80 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 120  
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e3fac _pthread_wqthread + 1176  
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e3b08 start_wqthread + 4  


Thread 4:  
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e3b04 start_wqthread + 0  


Thread 5:  
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001814e3b04 start_wqthread + 0  


Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):  
    x0: 0x0000000141d499f0   x1: 0x0000000000000e03   x2: 0x0000000000000e03   x3: 0x0000000000000001  
    x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000100000028   x6: 0x0000000004410103   x7: 0x00000000000010ff  
    x8: 0x00000000141d4500   x9: 0xf73a8b04d3660033  x10: 0x0000000104684060  x11: 0x0000000141e38000  
   x12: 0x000000000000233f  x13: 0x000000000000233f  x14: 0x000000000000233f  x15: 0x0000000000000001  
   x16: 0x00000001814dec78  x17: 0x0000000000001000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000104684058  
   x20: 0x0000000141e39840  x21: 0x0000000141e39840  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x000000016b9cf0e0  
   x24: 0x00000001b1dcf000  x25: 0x00000000000000d8  x26: 0x00000001b1dcf000  x27: 0x00000001b1dcc000  
   x28: 0x00000001b1dcf000   fp: 0x000000016b9cea10   lr: 0x0000000193d704fc  
    sp: 0x000000016b9ce970   pc: 0x0000000180a941a0 cpsr: 0x60000000  


Binary Images:  
0x1045d0000 - 0x1045d3fff videosubscriptionsd arm64  <4393dd0905a73139860528464675670a> /usr/libexec/videosubscriptionsd  
0x104758000 - 0x104793fff dyld arm64  <06dc98224ae03573bf72c78810c81a78> /usr/lib/dyld  
0x1809f2000 - 0x1809f3fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <1cbfa6a1a0fb3fc99264d3d30ca0e543> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  
0x1809f4000 - 0x180a4cfff libc++.1.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib  
0x180a4d000 - 0x180a6efff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <086faefd537e3954b23565f56653a2cb> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib  
0x180a70000 - 0x18112bfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib  
0x18112c000 - 0x181131fff libcache.dylib arm64  <9234c7627b253d1ba2b18cd9aaadbe2e> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib  
0x181132000 - 0x18113dfff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <50eeb933dceb3aa28a43dd3a791139ce> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib  
0x18113e000 - 0x181141fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib  
0x181142000 - 0x18114afff libcopyfile.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib  
0x18114b000 - 0x1811aefff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib  
0x1811af000 - 0x181214fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <42fe29ae709d39d9bc00f31af92baaf1> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib  
0x181215000 - 0x18122ffff libdyld.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib  
0x181230000 - 0x181230fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <5d50c01da0fb3538bce8415db84cf1eb> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib  
0x181231000 - 0x181236fff libmacho.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib  
0x181237000 - 0x181238fff libremovefile.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib  
0x181239000 - 0x18124ffff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <5d19da723b2d3036b96bbe9569d99d5b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib  
0x181250000 - 0x181250fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <9a69557f7f5d35e6b2bb4c8cb55b43b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib  
0x181251000 - 0x1812cefff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <253425c2089e3d4d99cc1d073d72efe5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib  
0x1812cf000 - 0x1812d3fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <1f70ae27eb2d31ecb98b4b45f5b82ad9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib  
0x1812d4000 - 0x1812d9fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <3a312c5c347d3fcab6227fb824849657> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib  
0x1812da000 - 0x1812dbfff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <70bb743b7bf53de1afdf6f7afcce1379> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib  
0x1812dc000 - 0x1812ddfff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <90fe2ed455e4396aa662e5e32fd80b84> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib  
0x1812de000 - 0x1812e4fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <45af7516ceab3b94905cd74b35f4eab6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib  
0x1812e5000 - 0x181322fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <515624006f30300186f77a218ef98326> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib  
0x181323000 - 0x18134bfff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib  
0x18134c000 - 0x181379fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib  
0x18137a000 - 0x181395fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib  
0x181396000 - 0x1814c1fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <6762e60b7af83d2e86468be0ac6b4fa0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib  
0x1814c2000 - 0x1814cdfff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib  
0x1814ce000 - 0x1814d8fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <5bd9385d98c83d0ba9d157e69c429638> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib  
0x1814d9000 - 0x1814e2fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <038fc12926e83453a11b59ef3b1096c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib  
0x1814e3000 - 0x1814f2fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <01327cdfaac23c388fadf36cf440f0e2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib  
0x1814f3000 - 0x1814f6fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib  
0x1814f7000 - 0x1814fefff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <7fc5e7245e09393aa5d003dceeffa74b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib  
0x1814ff000 - 0x181512fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <9bfe9e9e10b9385787a827c768ba54bf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib  
0x181513000 - 0x181518fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <7e526b97e5b039e6a1c78107321592aa> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib  
0x181519000 - 0x181519fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <39d037ec6db036179470ab258fc96c13> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib  
0x18151a000 - 0x181544fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <9bc6486ebaa83cc580e90415889c978d> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib  
0x181545000 - 0x181766fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib  
0x181767000 - 0x181778fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <39dcd0297ee130c891937f50ce23c2df> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib  
0x181779000 - 0x181b0ffff CoreFoundation arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation  
0x181b10000 - 0x181b20fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <3f8b35c8ab283b78a319327ea597212e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib  
0x181b21000 - 0x181b21fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib  
0x181b22000 - 0x181ba6fff IOKit arm64  <56754e706db43267b2e2bc4387e34f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit  
0x181ba7000 - 0x181c8efff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <21cc9796ecb933e8b3e12f53e04148f7> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib  
0x181c8f000 - 0x181c9cfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <63ddef9a83dc335a9df0bef913f437a7> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib  
0x181c9d000 - 0x181cb5fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <252187562a8c3e07b7f01473a16c00d7> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib  
0x181cb6000 - 0x181e1afff libsqlite3.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib  
0x181e1b000 - 0x181e41fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <816e5c2426243ca5a8e6b3b2b9521776> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib  
0x181e42000 - 0x1821f0fff CFNetwork arm64  <4f38683f50453eaa9a09eb6222eae139> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork  
0x1821f1000 - 0x1824e9fff Foundation arm64  <18908b96750c38988eb0d7028c656a6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation  
0x1824ea000 - 0x1825eafff Security arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security  
0x1825eb000 - 0x182656fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <0caa3f1372c637f791d1aae47629aed1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration  
0x182657000 - 0x18268cfff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <7d19be0f618136a1a3bc7e81caba4b6d> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib  
0x18268d000 - 0x18268dfff libapple_crypto.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libapple_crypto.dylib  
0x18268e000 - 0x1826a4fff libapple_nghttp2.dylib arm64  <8d5134e490ad3c298330609806547a9e> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib  
0x1826a5000 - 0x1826cefff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <93fac4c1f6b73383a9082c6a963da406> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib  
0x1826cf000 - 0x18277dfff libboringssl.dylib arm64  <8b812051a23e35b8a22e4c272887ecf7> /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib  
0x18277e000 - 0x182794fff libcoretls.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib  
0x182795000 - 0x182796fff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib  
0x182797000 - 0x182798fff liblangid.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib  
0x182799000 - 0x18290efff libnetwork.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib  
0x18290f000 - 0x182941fff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <36ff48f819553b0c9e92c9fb2aa1a4a2> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib  
0x182942000 - 0x18299efff libusrtcp.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib  
0x18299f000 - 0x1829a9fff IOSurface arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface  
0x1829aa000 - 0x182a4ffff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <50b5f5beeab037ffa5810a67e580bdbf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib  
0x182a50000 - 0x182d70fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib  
0x182d71000 - 0x182fe0fff vImage arm64  <8f3ffa6be7e43dfdaf027891d655a60e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage  
0x182fe1000 - 0x182ff2fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib  
0x182ff3000 - 0x183017fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <483df9b3d90331888b43bb65d802485f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib  
0x183018000 - 0x18303ffff libBNNS.dylib arm64  <982f32f4102133d2802ea5f81cdc13a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib  
0x183040000 - 0x183054fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib  
0x183055000 - 0x183059fff libQuadrature.dylib arm64  <5a98c0d39e0d38f89ce20797be797ac8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib  
0x18305a000 - 0x1830c9fff libSparse.dylib arm64  <6556be33563434b78e2ef1c80da99eb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib  
0x1830ca000 - 0x183155fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <4de8af8c7371382b9183e4dc14245445> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib  
0x183156000 - 0x183156fff vecLib arm64  <2d93d3f4573b313d81fc9104810f0f61> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib  
0x183157000 - 0x183157fff Accelerate arm64  <850c55e76100327ea543af936487944c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate  
0x183158000 - 0x18316efff libcompression.dylib arm64  <9a090a94c6463eefa5413f012a34d3a4> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib  
0x18316f000 - 0x1836b6fff CoreGraphics arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics  
0x1836b7000 - 0x1836bcfff IOAccelerator arm64  <83c3c1fcfd963ec4b3c15ca18ea71efe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator  
0x1836bd000 - 0x1836c2fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib  
0x1836c3000 - 0x18375bfff Metal arm64  <46fc1e5f11c5316991cb5d7a0aa46523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal  
0x18375c000 - 0x18376ffff GraphicsServices arm64  <85072ece665a3a86807f153e85476fed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices  
0x183770000 - 0x1838c9fff MobileCoreServices arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices  
0x1838ca000 - 0x1838ccfff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <7b5129072b7f3d128f701b1b950bcdf3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator  
0x1838cd000 - 0x18390efff AppleJPEG arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG  
0x18390f000 - 0x183ebffff ImageIO arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO  
0x183ec0000 - 0x183f23fff BaseBoard arm64  <4a9ddf31f3443b6e9a17e272aebe2b8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard  
0x183f24000 - 0x183f3bfff AssertionServices arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices  
0x183f3c000 - 0x183f44fff CorePhoneNumbers arm64  <2cacbb2a053f314d9c6b6df55b4cea0c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePhoneNumbers.framework/CorePhoneNumbers  
0x183f45000 - 0x183f89fff AppSupport arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport  
0x183f8a000 - 0x183fa2fff CrashReporterSupport arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport  
0x183fa3000 - 0x183fa8fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <3e27a71f9459361193f3e182dc87d3b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary  
0x183fa9000 - 0x18402dfff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib  
0x18402e000 - 0x18404dfff ProtocolBuffer arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer  
0x18404e000 - 0x18407afff MobileKeyBag arm64  <19ed6cab7991380796131d9815a7e3df> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag  
0x18407b000 - 0x1840affff BackBoardServices arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices  
0x1840b0000 - 0x18410bfff FrontBoardServices arm64  <1f63db3e11403909903a700f99bbafe5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices  
0x18410c000 - 0x184148fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <618c22ec2c98329f8bb23caa50a4f53c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices  
0x184149000 - 0x184157fff PowerLog arm64  <85efbdc068743b57a7dc8cf1115869ae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog  
0x184158000 - 0x184174fff CommonUtilities arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities  
0x184175000 - 0x184180fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <6ca17ea36c9b3d8a80b1b4d147ba35f9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib  
0x184181000 - 0x184485fff CoreData arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData  
0x184486000 - 0x18448cfff TCC arm64  <5b6e4c731ff931a499b5c45cfd742c6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC  
0x18448d000 - 0x184494fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <0ef300210d2a342195796022e2a17e73> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib  
0x184495000 - 0x184526fff CoreTelephony arm64  <3a7e603987983d8ca966b29eb8aa08fa> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony  
0x184527000 - 0x18457efff Accounts arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts  
0x18457f000 - 0x1845a8fff AppleSauce arm64  <708bf2e767363eaaae3d41e17e0a0e86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSauce.framework/AppleSauce  
0x1845a9000 - 0x1845b1fff DataMigration arm64  <3db16bbf04603c5da1bd70c06c7cb464> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration  
0x1845b2000 - 0x1845b8fff Netrb arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb  
0x1845b9000 - 0x1845ebfff PersistentConnection arm64  <644d574b0cb33cf0bcaa55f353b636d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection  
0x1845ec000 - 0x1845fdfff libmis.dylib arm64  <750810cf779d3946964aa5ee4a44f063> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib  
0x1845fe000 - 0x184704fff ManagedConfiguration arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration  
0x184705000 - 0x18470afff libReverseProxyDevice.dylib arm64  <7c2f9a593dd03a90855450c4b3b2208e> /usr/lib/libReverseProxyDevice.dylib  
0x18470b000 - 0x18471dfff libamsupport.dylib arm64  <6c1d65704dfc3b9b87980cd65560188e> /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib  
0x18471e000 - 0x184723fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <8cfed6ca663f30748dd58b598a23169d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib  
0x184724000 - 0x184725fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <4bf21a6ca33d3222bd1442c13450464d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib  
0x184726000 - 0x184729fff libutil.dylib arm64  <2f7e5961d4b734b496f3d85eae03acd1> /usr/lib/libutil.dylib  
0x18472a000 - 0x18476afff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <9c2f70ff46913e4f9dc66605475914f9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib  
0x18476b000 - 0x1847e1fff APFS arm64  <075ddba3fa093db78988256945f50ff9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/APFS.framework/APFS  
0x1847e2000 - 0x184813fff MediaKit arm64  <82856e94773c33f5a67a8eb4c1c6148e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaKit.framework/MediaKit  
0x184814000 - 0x18482cfff libSERestoreInfo.dylib arm64  <3cb3e784ed3e389894f58e4b9fc7bb4e> /usr/lib/updaters/libSERestoreInfo.dylib  
0x184831000 - 0x18486dfff DiskImages arm64  <198c6094f9c237698130c80de266469b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/DiskImages  
0x18486e000 - 0x184877fff libGFXShared.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib  
0x184878000 - 0x1848bffff libauthinstall.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib  
0x1848c0000 - 0x1848c8fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer  
0x1848c9000 - 0x1848d4fff OpenGLES arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES  
0x1848d5000 - 0x18495cfff ColorSync arm64  <5959a19f99dc3ed1b0553dc055c18347> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync  
0x18495d000 - 0x184986fff CoreVideo arm64  <740eb305ad133ba9ad42b2334b4c4ef5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo  
0x184987000 - 0x184988fff libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib arm64  <63de7396e5733ef8a0707e336ea72fd7> /usr/lib/libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib  
0x184989000 - 0x184af5fff CoreAudio arm64  <8c29fcd6f30b3943bf20b01aeb0e04f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
```

Comment: Are these builds onto your device from Xcode?  Do you have a paid developer account?

Comment: Yes I do have a paid developer account and yes, these builds are live on an iPad through Xcode. It crashes every 10 days approximately after reinstalling the app. Reset and Hard Reset do not work.

Comment: Installs via xcode are temporary installs and will stop running after a while unless they are enterprise apps.

Answer (score 0):

please add your device to XCode IDE and working with that app until you get that crash and then go to Window -> Devices and simulators and get that specific crash log file from that specific app on the apps-list and then send that more human-readable log file in here to help you out